# Свой "Окей Google" или как отследить начало запроса

Tags: python, распознавание

Есть идея сделать приложение на Python которое распознавало бы запрос и находило ответ в интернете.
Но это приложение будет работать сутками и нужно как то отследить фразу-начало, пусть это будет тот же "Окей гугл", но как это реализовывать?
Обычные слова можно распознать через SpeechKit или подобные, но не целыми же сутками отправлять записи голоса на сервер?
Приложение должно как то само распознавать начальную фразу, а потом только записывать и отсылать запрос на распознавание речи в SpeechKit.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать отслеживание определённой фразу без сервера и лишней нагрузки (что бы она работала постоянно в фоновом режиме так сказать)

Comment: то есть вопрос: как распознать фиксированную фразу без удалённых сервисов?

Comment: @jfs Да, именно

Comment: анализируйте входной аудиопоток, при получении волны, сходной по амплитуде с "окей, гугл" отсылайте ее в распознователь, если последний корректно распознал - отправляйте всё следующее за этой волной.

Comment: CMUSphinx имеет [“keyphrase search” режим](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qhow_to_implement_hot_word_listening). Чтобы на лету распознавать, [с gstreamer можно использовать.](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/gstreamer)

Comment: [пример кода на Питоне](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/swig/python/test/kws_test.py)

Comment: @jfs А кушать не много будет при этом? (Оформите как ответ, отмечу как правильный)

Comment: Про производительность не знаю, фиксированные фразы ещё 20 лет назад успешно распознавались, но Siri до сих пор требует подключения к сети для голосовой активации.  Чтобы ответ получился, не хватает описания процедуры тренировки модели, иначе плохо распознавать будет (я бы начал с фразы из 4 слогов минимум).

Comment: @jfs А CMUSphinx не работает с русским языком? Или как там всё устроено? Можно будет поставить русскую фразу?

Comment: @Mr_Epic: что происходит, если "CMUSphinx russian" вбить в гугл?

Comment: @jfs Понял, как ответ оформите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Mr_Epic: я не пробовал в действии, поэтому если у вас получилось настроить распознавание фиксированной фразы на русском, было бы интересно почитать ваши шаги и результаты.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать CMUSphinx, а для того, чтоб русский язык распознавал - акустическую модель cmusphinx-ru-5.2, например (ссылка для скачивания модели - https://es.osdn.net/projects/sfnet_cmusphinx/downloads/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Russian/cmusphinx-ru-5.2.tar.gz/). Плюс ко всему, Sphinx позволяет создавать свой словарь и файл грамматики, что сильно ускорит процесс работы приложения на ограниченном наборе слов/команд.

Пара полезных ссылок:

https://habr.com/ru/post/351376/ - статья на Хабре про использование Sphinx

https://cmusphinx.github.io - официальное руководство