# Подскажите чем распознавать активационную фразу на python windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, распознавание-речи

Нужно распознавать ключевое слово при помощи python 3.5, поток брать с микрофона, 
обязательно должен поддерживаться **windows**(snowboy например не поддерживает). Во время поиска слова не должно потребляться много ресурсов.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Свой "Окей Google" или как отследить начало запроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478010/23044)

Comment: @jfs, я пробовал pocketsphinx'ом, он процессор ест не слабо и часто ошибается.

Comment: нужно тренировать и правильные настройки использовать (читайте ссылки в обсуждении)